# Data storage shared with co-worker

Tags: storage

I would like to ask anyone out there who knows of a good free website that allows me to upload my gis data files to co-worker. Each project I am working on are quite large and would need to upload 1 GB each.

Comment: This isn't a GIS specific question.

Comment: Hi Probert, thanks for your question. I've closed it as it doesn't seem to have any specific spatial aspect, and because stack exchange is a network of sites, it is likely to get more responses on one of more general sites like stackoverflow.com. Thanks for your participation!

Comment: compress the geodatabase and then zip it up (high compress rate) then send by FTP. or http://www.sendthisfile.com/ one of many

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think Dropbox would be a good solution for you. It will automatically sync files within a certain directory. I think the limit for the free account is 2g, which sounds like it would work for you.

If you use [this](http://db.tt/meJI9Jh) I get a little extra space on my account :)

Answer (score 3):

A co-worker in the same office? Do you use servers for anything? Just make a shared folder with only you two given access to read/write.

Comment: MLowry, Her office is in Alburqurque while mine is in Las Cruces so that is 3 hours away.

Comment: @PROBERT So there's no server in common between your two offices? If so, "the cloud" (Dropbox, Amazon Cloud Drive, etc.) is probably your best bet.

Comment: Michael, we do have the server but from here to there takes hours for my co-worker to download to hers. That's why I am trying to find one that is quicker rather than putting on the server through between the 2.